# Does Queelag's Sister's name ever appear in DkS1?

Tags: dark-souls

Before fighting Quelaag in Blighttown, you can meet up with Quelana, and after defeating Quelaag to ring the bell, you can find Quelaag's sister, or "The Fair Lady".

Is her real name ever appear throughout the game? I know a few people who mistakenly refer to her as Quelana, but no one knows her real name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's never mentioned in-game and it's not in any official text either. She is only known as, as you mentioned, "The Fair Lady" or "The White Lady."

The [Giant Bomb entry](http://www.giantbomb.com/quelaags-sister/3005-21029/) for her says the same thing.

Answer (score -2):

No official source for this, but I've seen her called Quelaan in a few places.

Comment: http://darksouls.wiki.fextralife.com/Daughter+of+Chaos

Comment: However the question asks for any source *in-game*. Wikis don't count ;)